# Limit of the eigenvalues of a matrix function with some divergent matrix elements

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am a physicist and this is a math problem that I encounter when exploring impurity scattering with a general dispersion relation. The dispersion relation takes the form of   $E(k)=k^m$, where $m\geq 2$ is an integer.

---

The math problem is set up as follows:

$V_i(k)$ are locally square-integrable functions of $k\in (-\infty,+\infty)$ for $i=1,2,\dots N$.  When $k\rightarrow 0$, $V_i(k)=c_ik^{n_i}+O(k^{n_i+1})$, $c_i\neq 0$ and $\{n_i\}$ is a sequence of strictly increasing integers: $0\leq n_1< \dots <n_i<n_{i+1}<\dots n_N$.
Given an integer $m\geq 2$, define a $N\times N$ matrix function $M_{ij}(\omega)$ of complex variable $\omega$:
\begin{equation}
M_{ij}(\omega)=d_{ij}+ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dk \frac{V_i(k)V_j^*(k)}{\omega-k^m},
\end{equation} where $d_{ij}$ are complex constants.
The domain of $M_{ij}(\omega)$ is the complement of the real line for odd $m$ and the complement of the positive real line for even $m$.

Define  $n_c(m)=(m-1)/2$. $n_c(m)$ is an integer for odd $m$ and a half integer for even $m$.
I am interested in the case when
\begin{equation}
0\leq n_1 <\dots n_D<n_c(m)<n_{D+1}<\dots <n_N
\end{equation}
where none of the $n_i$ is equal to $n_c(m)$. This is always true for even $m$.

Since $V_i(k)V^*_j(k)=O(k^{m})$ for $D+1\leq i,j\leq N$, it is not hard to see that, the matrix elements  $M_{ij}(\omega)$ for $D+1\leq i,j\leq N$ have finite limits when $\omega\rightarrow 0$.  Hence we can define a $(N-D)\times (N-D)$ matrix $M^T_{ij}$ equal to the limit of the submatrix of $M_{ij}(\omega)$ between rows and columns $D+1$ to $N$ in the limit $\omega\rightarrow 0$. To be specific, for $1\leq i,j\leq N-D$, we define
\begin{equation}
M^T_{ij}=\lim_{\omega\rightarrow 0}M^T_{i+D,j+D}(\omega)
\end{equation}

My question is the following:

***Is it true that one of the eigenvalues of $M(\omega)$ goes to $0$ in the limit $\omega\rightarrow 0$ iff  $M^T$ has a null vector?***

An illustration of $M_{ij}(\omega)$ in the limit $\omega\rightarrow 0$ is given here: [Illustration of the behavior of $M_{ij}(\omega)$, $q=|\omega|^{1/m}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rOD.png) . $M^T$ is illustrated by the blue square.

---

In the following, let me explain a bit more about my understanding of the properties of $M(\omega)$

To help understanding the behavior of the rest of the matrix elements of $M(\omega)$, we compute a group of integrals:

Define a function of $\omega$ for integer $0\leq l\leq m-1$:
\begin{equation}
L_{m,l}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dk \frac{k^l}{\omega-k^m}. \label{eqSLmndefinition}
\end{equation}
Introducing the polar representation $\omega=|\omega| \exp(i\theta)$, we define
$a=\exp(i\pi/m)$ and a root of $\omega$: $q=a|\omega|^{\frac{1}{m}}$. $L_{m,l}(\omega)$ can be evaluated as
\begin{equation}
L_{m,l}(\omega)=-2\pi i \frac{\kappa_{m,l} }{m} q(\omega)^{-1+\frac{l+1}{m}} ,\label{eqKsum2}
\end{equation}
where for odd $m$,
\begin{equation}
\kappa_{m,l}=\begin{cases}
\frac{1 }{1-(-1)^{l} a^{(l+1)}} & \theta\in (0,\pi)\\
\frac{1}{ 1-(-1)^{l}a^{-(l+1)} } & \theta\in (\pi,2\pi)\label{eqSkappamn}
\end{cases};
\end{equation}
for even $m$,
\begin{equation}
\kappa_{m,l}=\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{1-a^{2(l+1)}}& \text{even $l$}\\
0 & \text{odd $l$}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I think the values of $\kappa_{m,l}$ are not important for my question, but I gave them above for completeness. With the above calculations, we can obtain an understanding of the behavior of the matrix elements of $M_{ij}(\omega)$ when $\omega\rightarrow 0$.

For simplicity, when $m$ is even, we limit ourselves to the case that $n_i$ are either all even or all odd. This means that $n_i+n_j$ is always an even number for $1\leq i,j\leq N$.

From the above integrals, we can see that many of the matrix elements of $M_{ij}(\omega)$ diverges when $\omega\rightarrow 0$. In particular, the $D\times D$ submatrix corresponding to $1\leq i,j\leq D$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
M_{ij}\sim c_ic^*_j L_{n_i+n_j}(\omega)
\end{equation}

which are strictly divergent because $0<n_i+n_j<m-1$ and $n_i+n_j$ is even for even $m$ (See the green square in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rOD.png)).
The $(N-D)\times (N-D)$ submatrix corresponding to $D+1\leq i,j\leq N$ have constant limits and goes to $M^T$ when $\omega\rightarrow 0$.  The rest of the matrix elements, as illustrated by the white region in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rOD.png), may or may not diverge depending on the value of $n_i+n_j$:
\begin{equation}
M_{ij}(\omega)\sim \begin{cases} c_ic^*_jL_{n_i+n_j}(\omega) &  n_i+n_j<m-1\\
O(1)  & n_i+n_j\geq m-1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

One observation is that with increasing row and column numbers, the matrix elements of $M(\omega)$ are less and less
divergent.